# Error occurred while access Microsoft.Extensions.HostingServices. Could not parse JSON file

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-core

I was trying to create a migration for an MVC ASP.NET Core 3.10 project using Visual Studio 2019. I got two errors:

1. An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not parse the JSON file.
2. No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I assume the first one is the problem, since I already have my DbContext set up as the second one asked.

What I've tried so far:

1. Rolling back to .NET Core 3.0
2. Using a name other than "InitialCreate" for the migration.
3. Installing EntityFrameworkCore.Design, EntityFrameworkCore.SQlite, EntityFrameworkCore.SQlServer, EntityFrameworkCore.Logging.Debug, EntityFrameworkCore.Tools through the NuGet Package Manager
4. Restarting the computer and trying again
5. Quadruple-checking that Startup.cs had my DbContext added, and that my DbContext has the constructor set up to take a DbContextOptions in its constructor, passing the input to the base constructor

What should I do about the first error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It turns out that my appsettings.json was missing a closing curly brace. Adding that in fixed the problem.

Comment: A comma separating the ConnectionStrings and the Logging was missing.

Comment: An unescaped backslash (such as in a connection string server name) can cause this problem, too.

Answer (score 19):

Luckily I came across this thread and I'm kicking myself for not taking the error message literally.
 There were plenty of hints...
[image]

The one reason the error doesn't just **POP** out is because its just a **warning**.

You can change this behavior in Visual Studio 
Goto Tools->Options.
Click Text Editor->JSON->Advanced.
Under Validation change `Show errors as warnings` to **False**

[image]

You still get the same message on the console..
But this change makes the error a little more dramatic that there is an issue.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The issue for me is that I had a typo in my user secrets `secrets.json` file. I was missing a comma after a property value.

For reference, you can edit user secrets in VS2019 by right-clicking on a .NET Core project and selecting *Manage User Secrets*.

Comment: for me too, i was missing a comma in appsettings.json. thanks

Comment: In my case, I had emptied out my `secrets.json` (deleted the content, but kept the file) but apparently you need to keep at least the empty curly braces in it `{}` or you'll get this error.

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar issue when following [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code) MVC guide. If anyone is having similar issue, check your **appsettings.json** file that your are not missing something. (What I did was to copy the code from the tutorial, it broke my code, but when I typed it in, code worked)

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue in **appsettings.json**. In JSON, I **forgot to add comma** after AllowedHosts. As soon as I fixed that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This error could be due to syntax error. In my case, I missed a comma(,) after "AllowedHosts": "*" in appsettings.json file.

[Comma missing in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Kxl.png)
[image]

After adding the comma, Build succeeded. Screenshot added below for reference.

[Build Succeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLkgG.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I created appsettings.Development.json on vscode and didn't save it. The compiler didn't know which appsettings file to use. It was resolved when I saved the appsettings.Development.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Strange ; i had the same problem and same warnings but all settings were fine .

i just Cut all text in Appsettings and pasted it again then got Fixed  !

Answer (score 0):

i was missing a backward slash in my connectionstring in the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Run/build the project instead, the real cause of the error (which could be typos) would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i marked wrong project as "set as startup project". this mistake causes application uses wrong appsettings.json file.