# .NET Core 3.1 CreateHostBuilder Cannot parse JSON file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I am experiencing an error when trying to run my ASP.Net Core 3.1 project. The error is at `CreateHostBuilder` within `Program.cs`

```
   public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
```

which has not been edited from the default ASP.NET Core Web application template from Visual Studio 2019. It gives the exception

> System.FormatException: 'Could not parse the JSON file.'

It does not however refer exactly to what JSON file it's failing to parse. Here is a [pastebin with all 3 existing JSON files it could be parsing.](https://pastebin.com/MU3tGRcL)

Here is the full error stack:

```
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Could not parse the JSON file.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at <filename>.Main(String[] args) in <filename>:line 13

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(ref System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader, System.Text.Json.ExceptionResource, byte, System.ReadOnlySpan<byte>)
    System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
    System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
    System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte>, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader, ref System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.MetadataDb, ref System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.StackRowStack)
    System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions, byte[])
    System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.ReadOnlyMemory<char>, System.Text.Json.JsonDocumentOptions)
    System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(string, System.Text.Json.JsonDocumentOptions)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.ParseStream(System.IO.Stream)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(System.IO.Stream)

Inner Exception 1:
JsonReaderException: '{' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'. LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 4
```

It began when I started to use VS Code instead of Visual Studio which I normally use. The project however **can run successfully on another Windows machine** that's only ever run Visual Studio. I've tried a few things and I'm out of ideas. Here are the steps I have tried:

1. Confirmed with 2 other colleagues that `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json` and `launchSettings.json` do not have syntax errors as resolved in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346541/error-occurred-while-access-microsoft-extensions-hostingservices-could-not-pars)
2. Confirmed they are all encoded with UTF-8 without BOM as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399015/could-not-parse-the-json-file-error-in-progam-cs-asp-net-core)
3. Closing Visual Studio 2019, deleting the .vs folder, opening and then running again
4. Closing Visual Studio Code, deleting the .vscode folder, opening and then running again
5. Switched branches and previous commits.
6. Confirmed there is no user secrets configuration within `.csproj`
7. Deleting the repo files locally and cloning it again
8. Restarting the PC entirely
9. Creating a new templated ASP.NET Core Web Application within Visual Studio. It ran successfully.
10. Confirmed that `args` value is a string array of size [1]. The [0] position is used and contains the string `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%`. The environment variable does not appear in `app.config` or within Windows. I confirmed `args` is still the same and functions with the test pure template project.

Comment: Please show us the value of `args`! It sounds like the JSON is not valid/improperly formatted.

Comment: This is probably referering to your appsettings, do you have an appsettings file? And more importantly is it validjson?

Comment: `args` is a string array with size of [1] with a [0] value of `"%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"`. I'm a newbie to .net core, so I'm unsure to where this string value is coming from. No results come from searching the project with that string. @phuzi

Comment: @MarkDavies I can confirm that I have checked `appsettings.json` with 2 other colleagues. There is no syntax error however I'll post it here (with censored db name) to confirm it.
`{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=<azure-db>;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}`

Comment: Could you show us your implementation of `CreateHostBuilder`?

Comment: @phuzi It is as the default within the ASP.NET Core Web Application template.
`public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });`

Comment: The problem is with how the app is being launched and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` is not being replaced with environment variable contents. Can you verify the value of the `LAUNCHER_ARGS` environment variable is set properly even if it's empty?

Comment: Apologies, I am not immediately sure where to look for `LAUNCHER_ARGS`. From searching on StackOverflow, [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590493/iis-fails-to-run-asp-net-core-site-http-error-502-5) says it should be in `web.config`. I do not have this file within my project and do not see anything mentioned of such environment variable within `app.config`. @phuzi

Comment: What about Windows/Command line environment variables?

Comment: @phuzi Running `set` within command prompt does not appear with `LAUNCHER_ARGS`. I have confirmed that `args` remains the same in the test project purely from the Visual Studio template and yet it still functions.

Comment: @ColdZippo post your JSON file in the question itself. `CreateHostBuilder` doesn't parse anything itself, it sets up .NET Core's configuration system. If that didn't work *all* .NET Core developers would have noticed. This hasn't happened, so the question will have to be closed as unreproducible

Comment: @ColdZippo in fact, the error complains that a *property* name starts with `{`. Is there a `{` mixed up in the JSON file somewhere?

Comment: Despite your claim that you had several colleagues look at your JSON and pronounce it OK, your probably is most likely in your JSON file. The error is pretty clear, even if doesn't tell you exactly which file is the culprit, there's only a small handful of possibilities.

Comment: I suspect that if you search for `"{` in the JSON file you'll find at least one result. According to the error message, it's at line 2

Comment: Here is a [pastebin with all 3 JSON files](https://pastebin.com/MU3tGRcL) that exist in the project (besides those in wwwroot folder). @PanagiotisKanavos I would notify mason also but StackOverflow does not allow multiple user notifications within a single comment.

Comment: @ColdZippo post the first two lines of the JSON file you used in the question itself. The error is clear - line 2 has an error, probably in the very first character

Comment: @ColdZippo if you don't know which file fails, you can easily test all of them by calling `JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(System.IO.Stream)` on them or `JsonDocument.Parse`

Answer (score 16):

Not to sound like a broken record, but anyone facing this issue, please ensure that your appsettings.json is properly formatted.

I found that in my case, escape characters were not properly set in my connection string. Instead of having .\\MSSQLSERVER, I had .\MSSQLSERVER.

If you have a test instance on your local machine, kindly take out the connection string for the cloud and replace it with that of the local machine (which should be simpler) and that should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, thanks so much

Comment: Same for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason it all of a sudden started erroring and this was the cause. But I checked my change logs and the specific change was checked in a while ago so it was strange it started suddenly. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in starting a webApi on the same version of Asp.net Core. The problem was missing a curlybrace in appsettings.json

Answer (score 4):

I got this error recently and the top comments weren't that helpful at solving it. So first of all this error 100% related to a JSON file not being formatted correctly. However the top comments don't really tell you which files you should examine to find the error.

A list of files you need to check to make sure it works:

- `appsettings.[environment-build]` (This is likely the source in 99% of cases)
- `serviceDependencies.[area].json`
- `Secrets.json`
- `launchSettings.json`

`Appsettings` is found in your project directory.

`LaunchSettings` and service Dependencies is found in your Properties folder.

`Secrets file` is best found by going to `Connected Services` (Note this applies to Visual Studio).

For my case my Secrets file was causing the issue. Note this isn't a complete list for every project ever made, but it should at least point you in the right direction instead of spending a few hours quadruple-checking your app settings files.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with the same exception i.e. *JsonReaderException: '}' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. LineNumber: 13 | BytePositionInLine: 0.*

When I examined appsettings.json file, I noticed a squiggly on the "}". This is where the problem was. Turned out that I had an extra "}" in my appsettings.json file. Some might have a missing curly brace. Rest assured, the problem lies here.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with a value in my  `appsettings.json` that contained a path where the backslashes in the path were interpreted as escape characters.

Changing `c:\local-export-folder` to `c:\\local-export-folder` (double backslash to escape the backslash) did the trick for me.

I saw that you also have backslashes in your file. Maybe try to escape them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to validate your json file through sites such us: https://jsonlint.com/
it helps you find the error easily.

Comment: exactly in my case i forgot to add a comma file. when the json file is improper it will give strange errors

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is working once `appsettings.json` file properly updated as:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was AWS settings which were enclosed after installing AWS nuget. Look out for something similar to below AWS configuration in your appSettings.*.json file:

AWS nuget added following code:

```
{
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "local-test-profile",
    "Region": "ap-southeast-1"
  }
},
```

whereas, it should be

```
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "local-test-profile",
    "Region": "ap-southeast-1"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the cause of the error was in the appsettings.json file. I had forgotten to add a comma to separate my two ***ConnectionStrings***.