# ASP.net Core 3.1 Could not parse the JSON file

Tags: json, asp.net-core-3.1

I have started the upgrade of my project from ASP.net core 2.1 to 3.1, but having an issue with reading the appsettings.json file. This file has not changed and I am getting the following error:

JsonReaderException: '0x0D' is invalid within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 64

When string value is in 1 line it works fine.
Example:

```
 "SELECT * FROM TabelName "
```

But when I add any line break it gives above error.
Example:

```
 "SELECT * 
FROM 
TabelName "
```

PS: It was working fine in .net core 2.0

Answer (score 3):

I think`0x0D` is the Carriage Return character (\r). I've had a similar problem where I had a path that contained backslashes where the backslashes were interpreted as escaped characters ([see my answer to a different question on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63410606/1022179)).

I don't know how to put multi-line strings in your file but knowing why it fails could possibly help you in your debugging.

I would've kept that statement on a single line.